# CustomeDateAdapter in Angular Material 6

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I have implemented a CustomDateAdapter as described here: https://medium.com/@esanjiv/working-with-custom-dateadapter-for-angular-material-2-datepicker-76d4446277dc

Now, I am doing the Angular Material 6 migration and I get the following error

```
core.js:1598 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'TRIDENT' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'TRIDENT' of undefined
at CustomDateAdapter.NativeDateAdapter [as constructor] (core.es5.js:792)
at new CustomDateAdapter (custom-date-adapter.ts:21)
at _createClass (core.js:9262)
...
```

core.es5.js line 792 is this:

```
_this.useUtcForDisplay = !platform.TRIDENT;
```

It seems that the platform is undefined.

I noticed that the constructor of the NativeDateAdapter has changed in Material 6, it also requires a platform as input.

```
constructor(matDateLocale: string, platform: Platform);
```

What I am missing? How can I implement a CustomDateAdapter in Angular Material 6?

Comment: Can you show us your code? Did you install Angular CDK? Angular Material + CDK version?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. Here is my fix.

```
// in your shared or main.module.ts
// … other imports
import {Platform, PlatformModule} from '@angular/cdk/platform';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // …
    PlatformModule
  ],
  exports: [
    // …
    PlatformModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: YourCustomDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, Platform]},
  ]
 });
 export class SharedModule {
}
```

And you haven't override the `YourCustomDateAdapter`'s constructor.

Comment: In my case I could resolve using only `imports: [.., PlatformModule]` OR using only `deps: [.., Platform]`

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by instantiating in my code a Platform object

```
export class CustomDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {

  constructor(matDateLocale: string) {
    super(matDateLocale, new Platform());
  }

...

}
```

Another option is to provide it with a factory

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: Platform,
      useFactory: platformProviderFactory,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

export function platformProviderFactory() {
  return () => new Platform();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rafa. I think this error points to another problem in your code. As far as I understand you should not instantiate the Platform yourself, but let Angular do that for you. Yes you can workaround the problem with your solution, but the real problem still exists.

Comment: In my case I had deps in the providers {....deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]} and when I removed it, it worked fine.

Comment: Have you got the `@Injectable` attribute on your adapter so the Platform can be injected?

Comment: I only provided the first code and worked. But when i passed the second {
      provide: Platform,
      useFactory: platformProviderFactory,
      multi: true
    }some toggle not working.so, used the first code to make things working. Thanks a lot.