# custom native date adapter no longer works since upgrade of Angular/Material from 5 to 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-6

I had a custom date adapter in my Angular 5 app:

```
import {NativeDateAdapter} from "@angular/material";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class CustomDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {

    parse(value: any): Date | null {
        if ((typeof value === 'string') && (value.indexOf('/') > -1)) {
            const str = value.split('/');
            return new Date(Number(str[2]), Number(str[1])-1, Number(str[0]), 12);
        }
        const timestamp = typeof value === 'number' ? value : Date.parse(value);
        return isNaN(timestamp) ? null : new Date(timestamp);
    }

    format(date: Date, displayFormat: Object): string {
        return date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0') + "-" + date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    }

}
```

defined in app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [...],
    declarations: [...],
    providers: [
        ...,
        { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: CustomDateAdapter }
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

It worked fine, but then it stopped when upgraded Angular/Material to version 6. This is the error I'm getting now:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'TRIDENT' of undefined
    at new NativeDateAdapter (native-date-adapter.ts:83)
    at new CustomDateAdapter (custom.date.adapter.ts:5)
    at _createClass (ng_module.ts:171)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (ng_module.ts:143)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (ng_module.ts:104)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (refs.ts:502)
    at resolveDep (provider.ts:416)
    at createClass (provider.ts:276)
    at createDirectiveInstance (provider.ts:135)
    at createViewNodes (view.ts:303)
```

I came across a similar issue [CustomeDateAdapter in Angular Material 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50608655/customedateadapter-in-angular-material-6) and tried a recommended fix including constructor

```
constructor(matDateLocale: string) {
    super(matDateLocale, new Platform());
}
```

now it produces following error:

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[DateAdapter -> String]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[DateAdapter -> String]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for String!
    at NullInjector.get (injector.ts:35)
    at resolveToken (injector.ts:332)
    at tryResolveToken (injector.ts:274)
    at StaticInjector.get (injector.ts:154)
    at resolveToken (injector.ts:332)
    at tryResolveToken (injector.ts:274)
    at StaticInjector.get (injector.ts:154)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (ng_module.ts:124)
    at _createClass (ng_module.ts:173)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (ng_module.ts:143)
```

Any idea how to make it work again?

Comment: Here's my solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/51279248/834003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with using `MomentDateAdapter` and a custom date format.

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from "@angular/material";
import {MomentModule} from "ngx-moment";
import {MomentDateAdapter} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';

export const ISO_FORMAT = {
    parse: {
        dateInput: 'LL',
    },
    display: {
        dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
        dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
        monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    },
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MomentModule,
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ...
    ],
    providers: [
        {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
        {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: ISO_FORMAT},
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `moment` read the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).

Simplified example on how to use a custom date adapter.

**Custom date adapter:**

```
import { Platform } from '@angular/cdk/platform';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject, Injectable, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DATE_LOCALE, NativeDateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';

@Injectable()
export class CustomDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(MAT_DATE_LOCALE) matDateLocale: string, platform: Platform) {
    super(matDateLocale, platform);
  }

  format(date: Date): string {
    // todo implement logic
    return new DatePipe(this.locale).transform(date, 'MMMM YYYY');
  }
}
```

**Usage in component:**

```
import { Platform } from '@angular/cdk/platform';
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatDatepicker } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { CustomDateAdapter } from './CustomDateAdapter';

export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'MMMM YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-month-picker',
  templateUrl: './month-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./month-picker.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: CustomDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, Platform],
    },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS },
  ],
})
export class YourComponent
```

Comment: CustomDateAdapter was exactly what I needed. Thanks! All the other solutions assume  moment.js is being used